# Access url using branches in svn

Tags: svn, branch

I have a test server with a http domain pointing to my repository on the server. Now that we have different developers working on same code, we decided to create branches for each developer. My question is, now that every one commits their code to their own branch, they should be able to test using the url. How can I make it possible so that we have separate url's for every branch within same domain.

Sorry, if this is repeated, but I wasn't able to find anything similar, not on stackoverflow or on internet which could solve my issue exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be running your website directly out of your repository in the first place. Subversion isn't meant to be used in this fashion, and you will almost certainly encounter problems with your code not working properly when compared to doing a proper deployment.

Each developer should be capable of testing their code from their own workstation, and commit code once it is working properly (or at other logical checkpoints).

If you need the code running on the server, perhaps to integrate with something else that can't be loaded on their workstations, best practice is to deploy to your server after committing, either via a post-commit hook script or a continuous integration system. To fully achieve this, each developer will need their own virtual directory or vhost on the server for their code to be deployed into.

Side note: Multiple developers working on the code does not automatically require that you have per-developer branches. Keeping everyone in sync means you'll need to perform numerous merges on a regular basis.

Comment: Thank you for response. So this is our staging server where we test our code prior to shifting it to the production. We commit the code and then test it using the url, so yes we have our test website linked to the repository directly, but that makes it quick testing.We then move the final tested code to the production. By creating branches, we have each developer (2-3), their own copies, test them on their local workstations, once good commit to their branches on server, test them again using the url, then merge it to the trunk, test again, once finally done deploy to the production. continued

Comment: I remember we had done this before, separate urls for every branch but don't remember how to do this. You mentioned about virtual directory, how can we point them to different branches.

Comment: So what you're saying is that what you're testing is not what you're actually moving to production. **Your testing is not valid.** Re-read my entire answer, especially the part about *not* running the code directly out of the repository, and instead deploying it to your server upon commit. I am not going to advise you on how to keep doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Hey, thank you, yes I understand the problem and would like to change the design. Can you please guide me something on post-commit hook script or a continuous integration system. I mean how can I transfer files from repository to some physical folder. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You really ought to do some research on your own first, then post specific questions.